# SQL - Get predicted dates if not available

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, common-table-expression, dateadd

I got a table #a as follows:

```
ID  | TYPE_ID | CREATED_DT 
============================
001 |   111   | 2019-08-28 
001 |   111   | 2018-08-12  
001 |   111   | 2017-08-23 
001 |   111   | 2016-08-14 
001 |   111   | 2015-08-17  
001 |   111   | 2014-08-11  
001 |   112   | 2019-05-31 
001 |   112   | 2018-05-28
```

I would like to get my final output as follows:

```
ID  | TYPE_ID | CREATED_DT 
============================
001 |   111   | 2019-08-28 
001 |   111   | 2018-08-12  
001 |   111   | 2017-08-23 
001 |   111   | 2016-08-14 
001 |   111   | 2015-08-17  
001 |   111   | 2014-08-11  
001 |   112   | 2019-05-31 
001 |   112   | 2018-05-28
001 |   112   | 2017-05-31 --Predict YEAR end dates if not available 
001 |   112   | 2016-05-31
001 |   112   | 2015-05-31 
001 |   112   | 2014-05-31
```

The final result set should predict dates upto 6 month end dates per TYPE_ID if the dates are not available(TYPE_ID = 112 has only 2 dates available). I'm sure we can do this using DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions to predict dates but a bit complicated for my knowledge. Any help?

Query that I'm trying, but not exactly there:

```
select *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, TYPE_ID ORDER BY CREATED_DT DESC) AS RN
   INTO #B
 from #a;

;WITH CTE(ID, TYPE_ID, CREATED_DT, RN)
AS(
 SELECT
    ID,
    TYPE_ID,
    CREATED_DT,
    RN
 FROM #B
 WHERE RN = 1   --Instead of RN = 1 I would like to get this till all 
                --available dates, so that I can go to recursive part for 
                --predicting non-available dates
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.TYPE_ID,
    DATEADD(yy, -1, CTE.CREATED_DT)AS CREATED_DT,
    CTE.RN +1 AS RN
  FROM #B AS A
  INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.ID = A.ID
                AND CTE.TYPE_ID = A.TYPE_ID
                AND CTE.RN < 6
                AND A.RN = 1
)
```

Comment: . . More information about the general rules is needed.  What if there were three rows or one row?  It is not clear how you want to generalize.

Comment: At minimum there will be atleast 1 CREATED_DT per TYPE_ID and I would like to get 6 dates in total. For example if there are 3 dates available, I would like to predict previous 3 years dates based on last available date, which is 2018-05-31 for 112 TYPE_ID

Comment: Updated with the query that I'm trying but not exactly there

Comment: any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Because there isn't an id to identify each row, you could use a rank window function to take the last row in this table. Then from the last row date you can dateadd -1 year to each date based on the rank. Then at the end UNION the intial CTE with the predictive CTE.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT d.ID
    ,d.Type_ID
    ,d.CREATED_DT
    ,RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY Type_ID
            ,Created_DT
        ) AS OrderOf
FROM datetable d
)
,CTE2
AS (
SELECT M.ID
    ,m.Type_ID
    ,DATEADD(Year, - 1, m.CREATED_DT) AS Created_DT
    ,M.OrderOf + 1 AS OrderOf
FROM CTE M
WHERE OrderOf = 8
)
,CTE3 (
n
,ID
,Type_Id
,Created_DT
,OrderOf
)
AS (
SELECT 0
    ,M.ID
    ,m.Type_ID
    ,m.CREATED_DT
    ,M.OrderOf AS OrderOf
FROM CTE2 M

UNION ALL

SELECT n + 1
    ,T.ID
    ,T.Type_ID
    ,DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, T.CREATED_DT)
    ,T.OrderOf + 1 AS OrderOf
FROM CTE3 T
WHERE n < 4
)
SELECT ID
,Type_ID
,Created_DT
FROM CTE3

UNION

SELECT ID
,Type_ID
,Created_DT
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Type_Id
,Created_DT DESC;
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for as TYPE_ID = 112 doesn't always have 2 records, it can have any records more than one. Also this query yields 13 records instead of 12. TYPE_ID = 112 gives 7 records

Comment: Do you want to predict based on all the dates or the last date? 
You can change the N in CTE3 to change the amount of iterations so you get 6 records.

Comment: prediciton should be based on last available date for a given TYPE_ID